# Examples of While loops

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am new to python and i am trying to learn while loops, i have written a program where it asks the user for their age, and after the age is entered, a sentence is printed and the program ends, but i want it to restart the question in the shell because i am sick of pressing f5 each time.

I have tried to put 'return' at the end of the loop but it does not work.

```
age = input('Enter your age: ')

while age:

    if int(age) > 0 or int(age) <= 5:
        print('you are', age, 'wow')
    elif int(age) >= 6 or int(age) >= 10:
        print('.')
    else:
        print()
    return
```

this is what i have done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop like this:

```
while True:
    age = input('Enter your age: ')
    if int(age) > 0 or int(age) <= 5:
        print('you are', age, 'very young')
    elif int(age) >= 6 or int(age) >= 10:
        print('.')
    else:
        print()
```

changes:

- I created a while True loop. This loop reruns the following code endlessly, because in this case the "True" is the condition. The loop executes the following code repetitively, until the condition is False, but it cant be false, because its hardcoded to "True".
- also I have put the input statement into the while loop, because the input() statement waits until the user submitted text.

I hope I could help you

Edit:
is it possible that you wanted to use *and* instead of *or* in this line?

```
if int(age) > 0 and int(age) <= 5:
```

and in this line also *and* instead of *or* and that it only runs if age is bigger than 6 and smaller than 10?

```
elif int(age) >= 6 and int(age) <= 10:
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close to your approach except for the `return` statement. You can use a `Boolean` variable to control if you want your loop to continue looping. Additionally, you can ask the user if they want to continue looping and depending on their answer, the loop stops or continues. Here is an example:

```
loop = True
while loop:
    age = input('Enter your age: ')
    if int(age) > 0 or int(age) <= 5:
        print('you are', age, 'wow')
    elif int(age) >= 6 or int(age) >= 10:
        print('.')
    else:
        print()

    # Ask user if they want to stop. Only yes or y stops the program. Otherwise it continues
    answer = input('Do you want to stop?')
    if answer.lower() == 'yes' or answer.lower() == 'y':
        loop = False
```

**Note**: `return` is used when you want to return a variable/value from a function. It does not `return` to the loop. You can read more about the `return` statement [`here`](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20return%20statement%20is%20a%20special%20statement%20that%20you,can%20be%20any%20Python%20object.).